# block spoofed referrer traffic claiming to be from your own site

Tags: spam, referrer, spam-bots

I'm getting over 10x usual site traffic with requests that spoof the referrer as my own site. I'm trying to block these with .htaccess

A bot's GET request looks like:

```
"GET /content/logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 1375
```

with referrer being like:

```
 "https://example.com/about/?DCr5fl=DUrOHiBCYY&Pq2CX=28e5Q9DX605&oNmQI=tC8cIAj7kd&9KrsuD=c1UsqSFUJHd&a4T5qN=pmzsA1EUiFP&We0W5LG=xKQXFA54UR&5QhZuc=w6vWoHd9BIZ&YL5hHO=WV3Z44cBA6y&6EvZF=5A6nqHE5WAp&cYb5X=CjeKi9GZNn&F8hb8AC=vtpuYCdqnD&929swgg=2eX70YZGWQN&OyWFlNA=Mt5m0tBrxt&iwsq6Pm=qD9g5DrV3Gh&"
```

user agent string:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

It's always something like "https://example.com/about/?xxxx=xxxxxxxx=xxxxx..." with random alphanumeric strings generated after the `/?`

I unsuccessfully tried blocking referrer by a string like:

```
# Options +FollowSymlinks
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} \/about/? [NC,OR]
#RewriteRule .* – [F]
```

and obviously I can't block my own domain.

Another way I tried was matching http host with referrer

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@@%{HTTP_REFERER} !^([^@]*)@@https?://\1/.*
RewriteRule .*\.* [NC,F]
```

but that also doesn't seem to be working.

Google Analytics sees a bunch of "humans" crawling pages in precise 60 second increments.

My logs are filling up with 2-3GB of data every couple of days and looking at my log using tail -f shows hundreds of requests per minute. I tried throttling requests with my firewall solution but it's not effective.

Comment: I think you can block malicious requests using Cloudflare.

Comment: Your RewriteRule - Are you aware you escaped the first / but not the second one?  Also, I'm not an expert, but what is the ",OR" doing at the end of that rewriterule.     Also, on that rule, did you have RewriteEngine On prior?

Comment: "something like `https://example.com/about/?xxxx=xxxxxxxx=xxxxx...`" - What is it about this referrer that tells you it's fake? Is it the URL-path `/about/`? Or the seemingly "random alphanumeric query string"? (Or both?)

Comment: ...do you use a query string at all on your URLs? If so, are the URL parameter names limited or follow a certain pattern?